# Filter the measure based on the other measure value(Without using the Sumx Function)

Tags: powerbi, dax, daxstudio

Please help me I am trying to filter  the data in 23 Qty Blank measure  Based on the check Month Wise .

```
Check Month Wise = IF(ISBLANK([23 Qty]),"D",IF(ISBLANK([22 Qty]),"N","V"))
```

This is Measure.
I have tried this dax
23 Qty Blank  = If( check Month Wise="V", 23 Qty,0) But its not working subtotal level its getting item code level only .

[image: Please find the attached link for Image]

This is which I am expected result [23 Qty Blank] By using the sumx function which i am getting ,But i need without using the Sumx is it possible to filter the data?

```
23 Qty Blank = SUMX(SUMMARIZE('Financial Data (3)','Financial Data (3)'[Group],'Financial Data (3)'[SEGMENT],'Financial Data (3)'[PRODUCT CATEGORY],'Financial Data (3)'[CORPORATE CUSTOMER],'Financial Data (3)'[REPORTING COUNTRY],'Financial Data (3)'[PAC ITEM CODE],"Final",if(Check Month Wise = "V",[23 Qty],0)),[Final])
```

[image: Please find the attached link for Expected Result Image]

Comment: Why can't you use `SUMX`? You are going to have to use it - but maybe not depending on your expressions for `[23 Qty]` and `[22 Qty]`.

Comment: when I use I got the solution with the sumx but dependency measures are there a that too i am createing with the sumx function at certain level the visual has been exceeding getting this error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an approach without using `SUMX`.

```
23 Qty (had 22) = 
  var tbl22 = 
    SELECTCOLUMNS(
      FILTER(
        SUMMARIZE('Financial Data Month',
          'Financial Data Month'[REPORTING COUNTRY],
          'Financial Data Month'[SEGMENT],
          'Financial Data Month'[PAC ITEM CODE],
          "Total", [22 QTY],
          "ID", [REPORTING COUNTRY] & "/" & [SEGMENT] & "/" & [PAC ITEM CODE]
        ),
        NOT ISBLANK([Total])
      ),
      [ID]
    )
  
  return
    CALCULATE(
      [23 Qty],
      'Financial Data Month'[REPORTING COUNTRY] & "/" & 'Financial Data Month'[SEGMENT] & "/" & 'Financial Data Month'[PAC ITEM CODE] IN tbl22
    )
```

Basically, it's getting all that exist in y22, and then return their y23 values.

You will need to add any additional columns above to ensure they are unique. In other words, add all that are used in `Rows` of your Matrix.

Comment: Thanks for your Replay But I need without using the SUMX

Comment: If possibile by using the summerize its fine

Comment: Share your expressions for `23 Qty` and `22 Qty`.

Comment: 23 Qty = CALCULATE(sum('Financial Data (3)'[QUANTITY SHIPPED]),'Financial Data (3)'[YEAR]=YEAR(TODAY())-1,'Financial Data (3)'[EXTERNAL]="External")
--------------------------------------------------
22 Qty = CALCULATE(sum('Financial Data (3)'[QUANTITY SHIPPED]),'Financial Data (3)'[YEAR]=YEAR(TODAY())-2,'Financial Data (3)'[EXTERNAL]="External")

Comment: Thanks a lot This is which I expected Result .can you help me in one more issue please when two measures multiply subtotals are not summerizeing by suing the sumx which i am getting the result but is possible by using the summerize function or any other Please help me

Comment: I don't understand, provide an example of what you mean.

Comment: I do have two measures i.e [23 Qty Price] and [Actual Values ]  And I want [Actual Turnover] =[23 Qty Price]*[Actual Values ] the sub totals are not summerizeing for this measure without using the sumx function I required Actually [23 Qty Price] Is Average. I will provide the pbix file

Comment: I don't fully understand the issue. Take a screen grab and annotate the issue.

Comment: For [Actual Turnover] =[Actual Values]*[22 Qty Price]   those two measures are multiplying . The [22 Qty Price] is the average Actually when it is multiplying with the [Actual Values] The Totals are also multiplying It means for example when i sum ilem level I am getting 900 in the subtotal its getting 1000 beacause of 22 Qty Price is average so I need 900 in Subtotal based on the item level

Comment: [Actual Turnover] = sumx
                                       (Distinct(Financial data [Item code]),[Actual Values]*[22 Qty Price])
this formula works but I need the without sumx By using the calculate is there any  chance ? Please read the above comment first

Comment: Nope, not possible. One must use one of the aggregatorX (SUMX, AVERAGEX, COUNTX etc...) functions when working with var tables. I'm still not sure why you are avoiding `SUMX`. Please help mark the answer above as Accepted for the benefit of all, as it solved your original question.